# Product filtering with multiple attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, product, collection

I want to display all the product with some  product attribute features.

ie; I have 3 products in kids category with attributes and categories like

Category: **boy** and **girl**

Size: **small**, **medium**,**large**

color: **black**,**red**,**white**

so I need all the product having **Category->boy, Size->small,medium,&color->black,white**.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to filter product collection

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id','your-category-id')
                ->addFieldToFilter('size',
                    array(
                        array('eq'=> 'small'),
                        array('eq'=> 'medium')
                    )
                )
                ->addFieldToFilter('color',
                    array(
                        array('eq'=> 'black'),
                        array('eq'=> 'white')
                    )
                );
```

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Comment: your code is not working

Comment: not getting the products.